# In what cases should the AUTOINCREMENT be used instead of the default ROW ID?

Tags: sqlite

In Sqlite, there are two ways to create monotonically increasing primary key values generated by the database engine, through the default `ROWID` mechanism or through the `AUTOINCREMENT` mechanism.

```
sqlite> -- Through the default ROWID mechanism
sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, foo);
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo (foo) VALUES ('foo');
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo (foo) VALUES ('bar');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM foo;
1|foo
2|bar
sqlite>
sqlite> -- Through the AUTOINCREMENT mechanism
sqlite> CREATE TABLE bar(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, bar);
sqlite> INSERT INTO bar (bar) VALUES ('foo');
sqlite> INSERT INTO bar (bar) VALUES ('bar');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM bar;
1|foo
2|bar
sqlite> -- Only the AUTOINCREMENT mechanism uses the sqlite_sequence table
sqlite> SELECT * FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name in ('foo', 'bar');
bar|2
```

The [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) seems to suggest that using `AUTOINCREMENT` is bad:

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.
>
> If the AUTOINCREMENT keyword appears after INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, that changes the automatic ROWID assignment algorithm to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs over the lifetime of the database. In other words, the purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from previously deleted rows.
>
> [With AUTOINCREMENT,] SQLite keeps track of the largest ROWID that a table has ever held using an internal table named "sqlite_sequence".The sqlite_sequence table is created and initialized automatically whenever a normal table that contains an AUTOINCREMENT column is created. The content of the sqlite_sequence table can be modified using ordinary UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements. But making modifications to this table will likely perturb the AUTOINCREMENT key generation algorithm. Make sure you know what you are doing before you undertake such changes.

---

**In what cases is it appropriate to use the AUTOINCREMENT keyword?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says that

> the purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from previously deleted rows.

So it is appropriate to use the AUTOINCREMENT keyword when you need to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from previously deleted rows. This might be needed if you have external references to those deleted rows, and must not confuse them with new rows.

Comment: Assuming you enable foreign keys, it's not possible to have an external reference to the deleted rows. Assuming you disable foreign keys, do you have a use case for when it is a good idea to keep an external reference to deleted rows?

Comment: Here, "external" means outside the database.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it :). When would it be useful for an external database to retain a reference to a deleted id?

Comment: Some synchronization mechanism that remembers the last synchronized row. Or printed on some piece of paper.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen Another good example is URLs. If you delete a page and I go to it via bookmark, I'd rather get a 404/410 error rather than an entirely unrelated page because you reused the ID. Since my bookmarks aren't in your database, you can't ensure integrity via foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

> "the purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from
>   previously deleted rows."

Out of context, this makes it sound like that's the **only** purpose. I would think one of the most obvious decision points for AUTOINCREMENT is whether or not you need the **guarantee** of monotonically increasing integers. In turn, surely that need most commonly arises because you need to know what order insertions happened in. One might prefer integers over timestamps for this because of: insufficient clock resolution, fear of wonky clocks, difficulty synchronizing if more than one clock source is involved, etc.

Of course, one can always construct off by one situations where a transaction finishes first but gets a higher number than a competing transaction. However, these seem to pretty much correspond to cases where two humans might disagree on which transaction "happened" first, so the guarantee of monotonicity is about is good as it gets, IMO. That's a guarantee SQLite offers if you use AUTOINCREMENT.

> "do you have a use case for when it is a good idea to keep an external
>   reference to deleted rows?"

Not so much a matter of whether it's a good idea: if humans see/use IDs in any form, it can be confusing if a number they thought was unique gets reassigned. Here's an example seen [in the wild](https://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11378). This is a subset of the range of needs for monotonically increasing IDs, but more common than you might think. Humans are good at subconsciously absorbing the fact that numbers "are supposed to" always get bigger. For example, in ye olde slashdot days, people could glance at your user ID number to gauge how long you had been a member. On slashdot, I guess a quick hover over the user name accomplishes the same thing and saves having to go look at their profile.